# Synchronizing the table on multiple pages in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

So, I am developing a web application for a client and I have encountered a problem. I want a specific row of data in multiple locations with in the database. I have already created the databases i am just having trouble in synchronizing it's column in multiple tables. As far as I know it can be done via forgein key but would I be needing a bridge table for it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far??

Comment: NVM, it's done already, thanks alot :)